# How to factory reset computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, windows-vista, black-screen-of-death

So, I have a dell laptop that was running Windows Vista Home Premium. I started installing Windows 7 Professional. However, it was hanging on "Completing Installation", and I read somewhere to hard reset it.

Huge mistake. Now it will not boot at all. The setup manager keeps saying it needs to restart, and all I can press is "OK". **And there is no repair option under the boot menu.** Whenever I try to boot from the usb, I just get a black screen with a cursor. I can, however, access the command prompt.

Also: Safe Mode of any kind just gives me an error about the installer can't run in safe mode.

**My Question:**

How can I get my computer to at least be able to boot up again so I can restart the installation?

**Other info:**

When I put the iso on the usb, I simply extracted it with 7-Zip. I realize I may need to properly burn it.

Comment: I've read that having any USB devices plugged in may cause some of the issues you are having.  Try unplugging all USB devices (if any) and reboot?

Comment: @TimmyJim Tried that. All it does is flash a blue screen with words, and crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get back into the installation by properly burning the iso to a usb. Here is the program I used: [ISOtoUSB](http://www.softsea.com/download/ISO-to-USB.html)

Make sure to select the "Bootable" option when burning.

Hope this helps anyone else! I do not plan on hard shutting my computer this time!